# DataTypeAttribute in MVC4

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following property in my MVC4 ViewModel:

```
[DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
```

And in my view:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.PhoneNumber)
```

What benefit does the DataTypeAttribute add? It doesn't seem to be doing any validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make an editor template called `EditorTemplates/PhoneNumber.cshtml`, MVC will automatically use it for properties with that attribute.

Comment: Note to lurkers: there's a bunch of these templates available here: https://github.com/srkirkland/Html5MvcTemplates